# filtrar objeto json por rango de fechas

Tags: javascript, json

```
  accounts =[
  {id: "1", name: "item 3", amount: "15" date:"10-10-2018"}
  {id: "2", name: "item 2", amount: "200" date:"9-11-2018"}
  {id: "3", name: "item 3", amount: "300" date:"16-12-2018"}
 ];
```

tengo un arreglo que almacena objetos json y los listo en una tabla, me gustaria saber si es posible filtrarlo por un rango de fechas usando javascript, pueden ayudarme? cual seria la manera correcta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay muchas maneras de trabajar con fechas en JS.

**Aclaración importante**: los meses en JS empiezan desde el 0, Enero es el mes 0 y Diciembre el mes 11

Lo más sencillo para trabajar con fechas en JS es trabajarlas en milisegundos, para hacer esto deberías descomponer tus fechas usando el objeto `Date`; en tu ejemplo no queda claro que formato estás usando, si `dd-mm-yyyy` o `mm-dd-yyyy`, voy a asumir que es el primero y que la primer linea del array el `18` es un error de tipeo, para descomponerlas podrías usar una función así:

```
function toMs(dateStr) {
  // desarmamos el string por los '-' los descartamos y lo transformamos en un array
  let parts = dateStr.split("-")
  // parts[2] es año
  // parts[1] el mes
  // parts[0] el día
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]).getTime()
}
```

esta función te va a devolver un valor en milisegundos que podés usar para comparar con otros valores que vos quieras, por lo que para filtrar el array de accounts por ejemplo podrías hacer:

```
let preDate = toMS("8-11-2018")
let postDate = toMS("10-11-2018")
let filteredAccounts = accounts.filter(function(account){
  return toMs(account.date) > preDate && toMs(account.date) < postDate
})
```

De cualquier forma si podés usar librería externas lo mejor sería usar **Moment.js** https://momentjs.com/

**Bonus función toMs en es6**

```
const toMs = dateStr => {
  const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split("-")
  return new Date(year, month - 1, day).getTime()
}
```

Las fechas son un tema complicado en cualquier lenguaje de programación, hay mucho más para estudiar que lo que se puede desarrollar en una respuesta en este sitio, se puede empezar por aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date

Comment: si lo único que trata es de filtrar fechas, no entiendo la aplicabilidad de tu primer código, para que descomponer la fecha?

Comment: en el penúltimo ejemplo, deberías reorientar el código a que funcione con el JSON que el tiene declarado, pues tu colocas las fechas como variables separadas cuando en realidad son valores que pertenecen a una estructura JSON

Comment: @shadow Las fechas en el json son en realidad un string. El formato de fecha json es diferente, algo asi: 2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z

Comment: sin embargo vuelvo al mismo punto, debes incluirlas para que el OP sepa como filtrarlas dentro de esa estructura, eso y que el formato de la fecha no esta condicionado a si esta dentro de un JSON o fuera de el

Comment: @shadow el primer código lo que hace es pasar las fechas a un formato standar para después poder compararlas, en este caso milisegundos, no se pueden comprar como strings directamente, por eso explico en la primer parte de la respuesta que para mí lo mejor es pasarlas a milisegundos o *Unix Time Stamp*

Comment: en el penúltimo ejemplo si lo miras bien, estoy usando la variable con el nombre que le puso el OP, el código está trabajando directamente sobre su json

Answer (score 2):

Puedes auxiliarte del método `filter` para realizar dicho proceso por medio
de la clave que eligas.

Primero tenemos declarado nuestro JSON asociado a una var llamada `accounts`

```
let accounts =[
  {"id": "1", "name": "item 1", "amount": "150", "date":"10-18-2018"},
  {"id": "2", "name": "item 2", "amount": "200", "date":"11-18-2018"},
  {"id": "3", "name": "item 3", "amount": "600", "date":"11-18-2018"},
  {"id": "4", "name": "item 4", "amount": "700", "date":"12-18-2018"},
  {"id": "5", "name": "item 5", "amount": "800", "date":"13-18-2018"}
 ];
```

**EJEMPLO 1**

Aquí necesitamos filtrar por la fecha, indicando que solo nos muestre aquellas
que sean mayores a `"10-18-2018"`

Como puedes observar hago `n.date` es n la var que uso para acceder a la clave 
`date` y hacer mi comparación

```
let busca = accounts.filter(n => n.date == "10-18-2018")
```

Finalmente imprimimos la misma variable

```
console.log(busca)
```

**RESULTADO FINAL EJEMPLO 1**

```
[[object Object] {
  amount: "150",
  date: "10-18-2018",
  id: "1",
  name: "item 1"
}]
```

**EJEMPLO 2**

Si ahora necesito aplicar un filtro para extraer un grupo de fechas, puedo hacer uso del operador lógico `AND` representado por `&&` de este modo

```
let accounts =[
  {"id": "1", "name": "item 1", "amount": "150", "date":"10-18-2018"},
  {"id": "2", "name": "item 2", "amount": "200", "date":"11-18-2018"},
  {"id": "3", "name": "item 3", "amount": "600", "date":"11-18-2018"},
  {"id": "4", "name": "item 4", "amount": "700", "date":"12-18-2018"},
  {"id": "5", "name": "item 5", "amount": "800", "date":"13-18-2018"}
 ];

let busca = accounts.filter(n => n.date > "10-18-2018" && n.date < "12-18-2018")

console.log(busca)
```

**RESULTADO FINAL DEL EJEMPLO 2**

```
[[object Object] {
  amount: "200",
  date: "11-18-2018",
  id: "2",
  name: "item 2"
}, [object Object] {
  amount: "600",
  date: "11-18-2018",
  id: "3",
  name: "item 3"
}]
```